# Is it appropriate to approach references based on interviewer comments?

Tags: interviewing, references, employees, united-kingdom

My partner had an interview for a teaching job which she did not get. The interviewer said, "check your references as one doesn't show you in good light".

She is relatively certain the reference is someone in her current school, likely a senior member of staff. Is it appropriate to approach this person and ask them why they gave a bad reference? What is a tactful way to approach them considering the knowledge came through the interviewer?

Comment: This might even be a legal issue.

Comment: there's no basis for legal anything!  If it's a personal reference, it's your fault for putting that person down.  If it's a professional reference, the party being questioned shouldn't lie, including giving a bad review.

Comment: If you partner suspect a reference at her current school is resentful of her why is that person a reference in first place.  This is one of the reasons you don't list your current manager as a reference, there is a conflict of interest, the manager simply might have wanted to force your partner to stay in her current position because they actually think she does a great job.  In the end you should only list references you know will present you in the best light, otherwise, what is the point of them?

Comment: @Ramhound In the UK, the school will always want to speak to the head of department.  You can't choose your references in this instance.

Comment: You need to clarify which reference was the bad one.  I would suggest simply asking the interviewer (without asking for details about why it was bad).  Then you can decide how to follow up - I would personally consider simply not listing that reference.

Comment: @Jonah welcome to the Workplace! I edited your question as it was collecting close votes. If you think I cut out the essence of the question, or missed something important, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/13202/edit) it.

Comment: @jmac That's absolutely fine jmac.

Comment: This could depend a lot on where you are. In the UK, it's apparently reached the point where an employer reference will do nothing more than confirm your start and end dates, due to fear of litigation. So a prod at the HR dept of an employer where you nominated a referee who overstepped might well lead to a quick retraction. As a rule when passing on an employer reference, just direct them to the HR dept who will be efficiently and officiously vague and cautious. If they want a named reference, pick anyone there you got on really well with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She needs to approach this situation very carefully as the last thing she would want to do is to make matters worse.

- Call her old boss and ask if she'd be willing to reach an agreement
  with you on what she'll say to future reference calls. It's at least
  worth a shot—the worst that can happen is that she'll say no. When
  you call, say something like this: "I'm concerned that the reference
  you're providing for me is preventing me from getting work. Could we
  work something out so that this isn't standing in my way?"
- If she feels that the reference her boss is providing is factually
  inaccurate, skip her and go straight to her old company's HR
  department. Explain that your boss is giving an inaccurate reference
  for you and that you are concerned she is standing in the way of you
  obtaining employment. HR people are trained in this and will be
  familiar with the potential for legal problems, and will probably
  speak to your old boss and put a stop to it. (If it's a small company
  and there's no HR department, I would advise contacting the old boss directly and
  politely explain that she's exposing her company to legal risk by
  defaming you and jeopardizing your ability to gain employment.)
- If all else fails, she may need to simply warn prospective new
  employers that the reference won't be a good one. And you do want to
  give this warning, because it allows her to provide context and
  framing for what they might be about to hear. If you don't, they may
  never tell you that the reference is why they rejected you, so the
  time to speak up is before they place the call. How she explains it
  depends on exactly what's behind the bad reference, but her goal should be to put it in the best possible light. For instance, if her
  relationship with your boss soured after a particular event, she
  could say something like, "By the way, I had glowing reviews from my
  boss at that job, but our relationship became strained toward the end
  and I worry that it could colour that reference." She would need to be prepared for
  questions about what caused the strain, of course.

If you think the statements made in the reference are untrue and believe that it then unfairly harmed your future work prospects you may be able to take the person to court for ‘negligent misstatement’. To do so, you must show that:

- The information in the reference is misleading
- Providing this misleading information has had a negative effect on
  your future employment.
- Your employer was negligent in providing a reference.

Alternatively, if you think there is an element of discrimination involved, you can bring your former employer to an employment tribunal.

As you are in the UK I would strongly advise you to get her to visit [this site](https://www.gov.uk/work-reference) for further information and what her rights are.

Comment: @michael-gruby Great answer +1

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In the UK jobs I have applied for have to account for at least 3 years of professional work and provide a reference for those years. If there is only the 1 person available to give that reference its a tricky situation.

Comment: isn't it quite possible that the person didn't do a good job and the reference is accurate?  I've never known a professional to slander a former employee on a reference call.  just food for thought.

Comment: @squeemish She didn't do a bad job, her pupils get great results and she has also got friends there who can vouch for how professional she is.

Comment: @Jonah is that all heresay from her mouth?  have you ever worked with her?  most people i know won't admit to doing a bad job.

Comment: @squeemish I see it from the results tables from her school and I also speak to some of her friends who are also her colleagues

Comment: @MichaelGrubey- I find it odd that you "have" to provide a reference you know will not speak highly of you. You don't "have" to provide anything. If she has colleagues she can use them references and explain the situation with the manager in person if it comes up.

Comment: @Ramhound There are specific requirements when completing a job application that state they need a professional reference for certain time periods. I also find it stupid not only odd but that's the way it is.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey - These social or legal requirements?

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure. If they are not completed the application for would not be accepted. Could be legal to prove information provided is accurate. Never had to worry about the reason why before.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey - I suppose it does not matter considering even if its social requirement unless the author's partner can get a face to face the bad reference or missing reference cannot be explained.

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume all bad references are the result of saying negative things. A lot of times its because they're just mediocre. A reference of "She was an adequate teacher." isn't very helpful. Also, some people don't know how to give a good reference.

This is why you have to be very careful in picking professional references. Make sure you have their permission first. Let them know what the job requires and why you think you'll be a good fit. You don't have to put words in their mouth, but provide some background information. It could be a private school that emphasises teacher's academic qualities and is less interested in discipline where as a troubled school may be the opposite.